# AngularJS HTML5 mode with UI Router on apache

Tags: angularjs, html, apache, mod-rewrite, angular-ui-router

I had turned on the html 5 mode on my angular(1.5.8) app a few days back with this code:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true,requireBase:true}).hashPrefix('!');
```

Later I read [configuring apache server for html5 mode with ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode).

After doing these settings, I am facing 2 problems:

1. Browser reload, redirects to home page for every deep nested app link.
2. Any link coming from outside(via email) always redirects to the homepage.

I have played with

1. mod_rewrite  as-in using `<Directory>`, `FallbackResource` on apache.
2. changing paths to assets in the index.html (using relative URI and full qualified URI)
3. adding/removing the **base** HTML tag. (trying options like '/', '`<sitename>`')

But I am yet to overcome these problems.

Here is the detailed setup on my localhost:

1. I am deploying to apache via Virtual Host(and not .htaccess).
2. My deployment directory is /Users/`<name>`/Sites/`<sitename>` (I am on mac OS)
3. My index.html in-parts is as follows:

   ```
       <head>
         <base href="/">
         <!-- SPELLS 1-->
           <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
           <!-- more scripts / css et al -->
       </head>
   ```
4. My Apache(2.4.28) config is as follows:

   ```
       <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName <servername>
       DocumentRoot "/Users/<name>/Sites/<sitename>"
       #LogLevel debug
       LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
       RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
       RewriteRule ^ - [L]
       RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       Require all granted

       </VirtualHost>
   ```

Can anyone help me with the exact setup?

Comment: The closest that I have come to get it to working is:: The deep nested url sticks to the browser(it is not redirected to index.html) but apache returns index.html as response to all my assets(js/css), and changes their mime type to text/html.

Comment: See [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/joepKO?p=preview). Try accessing the url outside plunkr, it breaks::  [here](https://run.plnkr.co/w8IZFWKDnAikNjYY/#/level2)

Comment: The same [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/joepKO?p=preview) It breaks for HTML5 mode [With html5 mode](https://run.plnkr.co/w8IZFWKDnAikNjYY/level2) **Apache 404 Not Found**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of the`L` flag unless you plan on rewriting the URL more than once (it only ends the current iteration, and the rewritten URL goes through the rules again). You don't need the `Indexes` option and the directory test unless you want Apache to do automatic listing of directory contents. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [END]
```

Comment: Goes into an infinite loop between the destination url and the homepage url.

Comment: I guess all this connected, after the change you suggested, I changed the <base/> href value to "." and I get this error in console, with the deep nested url redirected to my app's 404 page.
**Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http:' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localwc.in' and URL 'http://localwc.in/emailverify-dc2cc653ce05cd03b9486fdbfa6b0794a35a4a4c81bff721ba8e6030eb10f65c-verify'.**

Comment: Put trace up to 8, and look at the logs, you're doing something wrong that we can't see.

Comment: That looks correct to me. Isn't the whole point to serve the same HTML file because the content routing is done in client-side JS? Show the log for a static file request (that is serving the wrong file).